# Easiest way to insert ModernCV based CV into another Latex document

Tags: moderncv

I have my CV done using the ModernCV template. I am now working on a research proposal that requires me to insert the CV in the middle of the proposal, but still keep the page numbering and headers consistent with the rest of the proposal. Is there a clever way to do it without rewriting the whole CV?

Comment: Compile your CV without page numbers (`\nopagenumbers` in moderncv). Include the pdf of CV in to the research proposal using `pdfpages`. Use `page command` to insert page numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Following @HarishKumar's advice from the comment, I

1. Compiled the CV with an added `\nopagenumbers` setting
2. Inserted the CV using the command `\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={}]{CV.pdf}`. The bit `pagecommand={}` sorted out the page numbering and headers  beautifully.